# Changing a global variable in an function JS

Tags: javascript

I have looked online about changing variables in an function but still doesn't work.

I'm trying to change the global variable in a function. An object with numbers are multiplied by each other. The function will be use several time with different global variables. so don't want to use there names directly.

**HERE IS THE CODE**

```
var homeTeamOppw = {"last_gp": 0.2, "2nd_gp": 0.2, "3rd_gp": 0.8, "4th_gp": 0.4, "5th_gp": 0.8};
ans = 0;

function timesArrayitems(teamOpp, array){
  var num = 1;

  for(item in array){
    num = num * array[item];
  }

  teamOpp = num;
}

timesArrayitems(ans, homeTeamOppW);
console.log(ans);
```

The ans come out as undefine. Can someone explain please and thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference

Comment: Your not actually updating `ans` in `timesArrayitems()`, you're passing it in as a reference,  where it's being used as a `local var teamOpp` scoped inside the `function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function only changes the local copy, `teamOpp`. You should return a value and set `ans` to that.

```
var homeTeamOppW = {"last_gp": 0.2, "2nd_gp": 0.2, "3rd_gp": 0.8, "4th_gp": 0.4, "5th_gp": 0.8};
ans = 0;

function timesArrayitems(array){ // note only one param
    var num = 1;

    for(item in array){

      num = num * array[item];
    }

    return num; // note return value

}

 ans = timesArrayitems(homeTeamOppW);
 console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to play with global scope and want to pass ans, ans need to be an object instead of just a variable as when you call a function it will be passed by value and if object is passed that is then passed by reference.

Code Snippet:

```
var homeTeamOppw = {"last_gp": 0.2, "2nd_gp": 0.2, "3rd_gp": 0.8, "4th_gp": 0.4, "5th_gp": 0.8};
ans = {val:0};

function timesArrayitems(teamOpp, array){

var num = 1;

for(item in array){

    num = num * array[item];
}

    teamOpp.val = num;

}

 timesArrayitems(ans, homeTeamOppw);
 console.log(ans);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FGp47/)

Comment: While this works, it's a weird way to solve this problem IMO.

Comment: I wanted to explain why his ans variable is always zero and not getting updated in the outer scope

Comment: Right; your explanation of the problem is correct, I just think your _solution_ is weird, using an object instead of returning a value. It seems like an overly complicated fix.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean something like this:

```
var homeTeamOppw = {"last_gp": 0.2, "2nd_gp": 0.2, "3rd_gp": 0.8, "4th_gp": 0.4, "5th_gp": 0.8};
ans = 0;

function timesArrayitems(array){
  var num = 1.0;

  for(item in array){
    num = num * array[item];
  }
  return num;
}

ans = timesArrayitems(homeTeamOppw);
console.log(ans);
```

ans returns 0.01024000004 (don't know if that is the expected output).

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: It isn't. Probably just submitted while the answers were flying in :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've got a few things going on here:

First, when I run your code I get a reference error because `homeTeamOppW` is not defined. You have a typo.

Second you never actually update `ans`; it gets passed by value. So it will never be changed from 0.

That being said, when I run your code (changing `homeTeamOppW` to `homeTeamoppw`) it prints `0` which is what I would expect.

If you change the function to return a value as @Mathletics shows and fix the typo, I think it does what you want. Alternatively, you can just directly reassign `ans` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The function will have its own copy (local to the function) and will not actually modify the content of your global var ans. Instead of passing ans as a parameter, you can try to assign whatever value the function is returning inside the function body.

Thanks